# Is there a specific order to complete Saints Row 2?

Tags: saints-row-2

Is there a specific order to complete SR2?

> I remember playing once and Gat got killed, but then later playing against a different gang he was still there for cut-scenes.

This made me thing that I may have done something out of order.

Comment: Are you asking how to complete the game with Gat surviving?

Comment: Well I don't mind, if he dies. I was wondering more so if there was an order. Since he did die, but was needed for a story line somewhere else it made me feel like it was played out of order.

Comment: No he's asking why if the game is non-linear do the cutscenes not take into consideration deaths of killable characters, and even though the game is non-linear is there a suggested order to complete the content so that this isn't an issue.

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought you meant he survived on another playthrough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three sets of gang missions in Saints Row 2, and each gang has a "sub-plot line" you can complete independently, although the missions within each line can't be completed outside of their set order.

Each gang mission line has its own central "Saints Row Lieutenant" who is most central to that part of the story.  The events of each are not related until all are completed, when you unlock another set of story line missions.

That said:

> Gat doesn't die in Saints Row 2 - he's injured during the Ronin quest line, and hospitalized.  You save him from the hospital shortly afterwards.  There's no way to get Gat killed permanently in this game.

You may be forgetting the rescue operation, which brings this character back into your group.  He plays a role in later missions.

Comment: Perfect, I must not have made it to that point in that play-through. This is exactly what I was looking for thank you.