# Does it matter what order I do the missions in Saint's Row 2?

Tags: saints-row-2

I randomly decided to do all the Ronin missions first in SR2. However, a character dies in Bleeding Out, which means they won't be in the rest of the game (I assume). Would they have appeared in cutscenes or plots for other missions if I had done those missions before Bleeding Out?

To be specific:

> Not Gat, who is addressed in [another question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73959/is-there-a-specific-order-to-complete-saints-row-2) but Aisha.

Comment: The tl;dr is you may think that guy's dead but he isn't :)

Comment: @agent86 Not Gat. I didn't want to say who due to spoilers, but the women at the start of the mission, which isn't addressed in the other question.

Comment: Ah, gotcha,  sorry.  You do know you can mark spoilers with `>!` though?  Might be useful markup if this sort of thing comes up again for you.

Comment: @agent86 No, I didn't know that. Seems silly to me as it won't work on text-only browsers, but sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this other character who actually *does* die has no other impact on the plot.  They are not mentioned and does not appear in the game other than in the Ronin missions.

The in-game reason for this is:

> She faked her death in Saints Row, so she's keeping a low profile throughout this game.

As far as the character who looks dead but survived is concerned:

> Gat is traumatized by the experience, although he doesn't really talk about it in Saints Row 2 much, outside of the Ronin storyline.  It comes back to haunt him later in the series, but saying more than that would be spoilers, sweetie :)